# I am getting this error for kids category and the game is not publishing in appstore

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I don't use Unity ads, I just use admob ads, how can I solve this problem?

Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category

We noticed that your Kids Category app includes analytics, advertising and collects, transmits, or has the ability to share personal information or device information with third parties. Specifically:

Your app includes third-party analytics or third-party advertising with the ability to collect, transmit or share identifiable information, including, for example, IDFA. We found that your app references the ASIdentifierManager API, which provides access to a user's IDFA, in the following location(s) in your binary:

• /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport

• KidsGAMES

• Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework

It would be appropriate to remove all instances of “ASIdentifierManager” from your app, even if they are not utilized in your app's functionality.

Comment: What about not any ads at all?

Comment: I just use admob ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is **NO**- You cannot have **third-party advertising** for apps in kids category. Refer link below

If your app is specific to kids category,

1. Remove all analytics and advertisements from app
2. Change monetization from advertisements to in-app purchase. Make sure parental control is implemented for in-app purchases.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#kids-category

> You must comply with applicable privacy laws around the world relating
> to the collection of data from children online. Be sure to review the
> Privacy section of these guidelines for more information. **In
> addition, Kids Category apps may not send personally identifiable
> information or device information to third parties. Apps in the Kids
> Category should not include third-party analytics or third-party
> advertising.** This provides a safer experience for kids. In limited
> cases, third-party analytics may be permitted provided that the
> services do not collect or transmit the IDFA or any identifiable
> information about children (such as name, date of birth, email
> address), their location, or their devices. This includes any device,
> network, or other information that could be used directly or combined
> with other information to identify users and their devices.
> Third-party contextual advertising may also be permitted in limited
> cases provided that the services have publicly documented practices
> and policies for Kids Category apps that include human review of ad
> creatives for age appropriateness.

Comment: so it doesn't even accept admob ads?

Comment: review guideline says "third-party advertising". Doesn't mention admob, also it says on last time about limited cases with contextual advertisements is permitted

Comment: but i would say even admob is not allowed  ( specially for kids app ). you might want to try contacting admob support to check with them if there is any setting available that will permit your app

Comment: Thank you for information